# Hi speed via not>>not. Why?

Tags: performance, dll, f#

I did a dll library plnd.dll for predicate palindrom string:

```ml
let IsPalindromLib (str:string)=
  let rec fn(a,b)=a>b||str.[a]=str.[b]&&fn(a+1,b-1)
  fn(0,str.Length-1)
```

And checked the speed:

```ml
#time
#r "c:/libs/plnd.dll"
open Plnd
let IsPalindrom (str:string)=  //equal library function
  let rec fn(a,b)=a>b||str.[a]=str.[b]&&fn(a+1,b-1)
  fn(0,str.Length-1)
let lst=[1..10000000]|>List.map string
let _ = lst|>List.filter IsPalindrom //from this code
// CPU time = 0.250 (+-20)
let _ = lst|>List.filter (IsPalindromLib) //from library
// CPU time = 0.500 (+-20)
let _ = lst|>List.filter (IsPalindromLib>>not>>not) //from library>>not>>not
// CPU time = 0.250 (+-20)
```

Calling the function defined whithin this code is faster than calling the function in the library, this is normal. But using composition predicate `not>>not` (boolean) when calling the external function  - **SPEEDS UP ???**

Comment: Try reversing the order of the `IsPalindromLib` calls so the one with `not >> not` comes first. The extra delay is probably caused by loading the .dll/JIT cost.

Comment: I am confirming that I was able to replicate it, it is really happening and is in no way caused by order of the lines. Trying to dig deeper now.

Comment: ops - correct error in function fn(a+1,a-1) change to fn(a+1,**b**-1) - time play via not>>not not changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done some research in this area and must say that this really happens. What is the reason behind this behaviour? Apparently it is caused by the optimizer. I am afraid that I don't have enough knowledge about the code optimizer to describe the reasons, so I may only guess. This is the code I have worked with:

```
open plnd
let lst=[1..10000000]|>List.map string

let inline fn a = x.IsPalindromLib a
let fn2 = x.IsPalindromLib
```

then I have tested the times for several different cases: Debug/Release configuration, method IsPalindromLib defined as inline/not inline in the module, FSI flag optimizer on/off. Here are the results of each query incl. time of execution.

```
//debug config, optimizer is on, library has the method as non-inline
let _ = lst|>List.filter (x.IsPalindromLib >> not >> not);; //0.98 - 1.01
let _ = lst|>List.filter (x.IsPalindromLib);;   //1.13 - 1.16
let _ = lst|>List.filter (fn);;                 //1.13 - 1.16
let _ = lst|>List.filter (fn>>not >> not);;     //1.14 - 1.18
let _ = lst|>List.filter (fn2);;                //1.14 - 1.16
let _ = lst|>List.filter (fn2>>not >> not);;    //0.96 - 0.99

//debug config, optimizer is on, library has the method as inline    
let _ = lst|>List.filter (x.IsPalindromLib >> not >> not);; //0.82 - 0.84
let _ = lst|>List.filter (x.IsPalindromLib);;   //0.82 - 0.84
let _ = lst|>List.filter (fn);;                 //0.81 - 0.85
let _ = lst|>List.filter (fn>>not >> not);;     //0.81 - 0.85
let _ = lst|>List.filter (fn2);;                //0.18 - 0.22
let _ = lst|>List.filter (fn2>>not >> not);;    //0.18 - 0.22

//debug config, optimizer is off, library has the method as inline
let _ = lst|>List.filter (x.IsPalindromLib >> not >> not);; //1.63-1.67
let _ = lst|>List.filter (x.IsPalindromLib);;   //1.15 - 1.17
let _ = lst|>List.filter (fn);;                 //1.15 - 1.17
let _ = lst|>List.filter (fn>>not >> not);;     //1.63 - 1.67
let _ = lst|>List.filter (fn2);;                //1.14 - 1.16
let _ = lst|>List.filter (fn2>>not >> not);;    //1.63-1.67

 //debug config, optimizer is off, library has the method as not inline
let _ = lst|>List.filter (x.IsPalindromLib >> not >> not);; //1.66 - 1.68
let _ = lst|>List.filter (x.IsPalindromLib);;   //1.15 - 1.18
let _ = lst|>List.filter (fn);;                 //1.13 - 1.17
let _ = lst|>List.filter (fn>>not >> not);;     //1.66 - 1.68
let _ = lst|>List.filter (fn2);;                //1.17 - 1.18
let _ = lst|>List.filter (fn2>>not >> not);;    //1.66 - 1.68

//release config, optimize is off in FSI, library has the method as inline
let _ = lst|>List.filter (x.IsPalindromLib >> not >> not);; //1.63-1.67
let _ = lst|>List.filter (x.IsPalindromLib);;   //1.15 - 1.17
let _ = lst|>List.filter (fn);;                 //1.15 - 1.17
let _ = lst|>List.filter (fn>>not >> not);;     //1.63 - 1.67
let _ = lst|>List.filter (fn2);;                //1.14 - 1.16
let _ = lst|>List.filter (fn2>>not >> not);;    //1.63-1.67

 //release config, optimize is off in FSI, library has the method as not inline
let _ = lst|>List.filter (x.IsPalindromLib >> not >> not);; //0.83-0.85
let _ = lst|>List.filter (x.IsPalindromLib);;   //0.34 - 0.37
let _ = lst|>List.filter (fn);;                 //0.35 - 0.50
let _ = lst|>List.filter (fn>>not >> not);;     //0.81 - 0.87
let _ = lst|>List.filter (fn2);;                //0.37 - 0.45
let _ = lst|>List.filter (fn2>>not >> not);;    //0.82 - 0.88
```

From these measurements, we can say that the fact that calling `x.IsPalindromLib >> not >>not` is faster than calling it normally is caused by the optimizer.

Comment: my assumption - composition not>>not compile slow extern call into new inline function is not used extern call

Answer (score 0):

Might just be that the interpreter loads the library function when it's first called.  Try reversing the order of the last two statements:

```
let _ = lst|>List.filter (IsPalindromLib>>not>>not) //from library>>not>>not
let _ = lst|>List.filter (IsPalindromLib) //from lirary
```

and see which one's faster. If this time the call without >>not>>not is faster, you're probably just looking at some interpreter issue of function loading or result caching or something like that.